# How to combine multiple condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1

```
ID 

12
21
12
21
...
```

Conditon

1)

I need to check either id should 12 or id should be 21. It should not be other numbers.

Below query is working

```
SELECT distinct ltrim(id) from table1 where ltrim(id) = '12' or ltrim(id) = '21')
```

2)

I dont need muliple number, always 12 or always 21, It should not be mixed, like

```
id

12
12
12
```

or

```
id

21
21
21
```

Below query is working

```
Declare @0_Recorddup int = 0
SELECT @0_Recorddup = Count(id) from (SELECT distinct id from table1) t1
if (@0_Recorddup = 0) or (@0_Recorddup > 1)  
begin
 ''error message
end
```

How to merge a both query, can anyone help me....

Comment: What are you asking?  I don't understand what you want as an end result

Comment: He obviously does not speak SQL on basic level but tries to get us do his work instead of learning the language he is using. THis is the most ridiculous way to compare a number I have seen in my life.

Answer (score 3):

> ltrim(id) = '12'

You store id's - a numeric value - as a string? I am sorry, but I hope you program better.

For integers it is simple like in most other languages:

> id = 12

and yes, etc. aredoable. I would suggest you grab some book about SQL and start learnng basics. Seriously.

> I need to check either id should 12 or id should be 21. It should not be other numbers.

Simple. Trivial. Like in any other programming language:

> id = 12 OR id = 21

alternative in SQL:

> id IN (12, 21)

that is not as nice for 2 numbers but gets in handy fast.

"SQL for Dummies" (IBAM 1118607961, available through amazon etc.) is a decent book for someone at your level. Explains the basics. Like how not to compare numbers as strings.